# can't use increment operation in Bash when error option is enabled

Tags: bash

Why doesn't the following snippet work ?

```
set -ue

inc=0
((inc++))
((inc++))
echo $inc
echo Here
[output nothing, return code 1]
```

But when disabling the '-e' it does work as intended? I ran this with "GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release"

Comment: This is one reason why the use of `set -e` is discouraged. There are too many commands that can have a non-zero exit status without actually indicating an error.

Comment: [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) discusses this directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of this (from the `bash` man page):

> *((expression))*
>
> The  expression  is  evaluated  according to the rules described below
>   under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the  expression  is 
>   non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1. 
>   This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".

So when `inc` is `0` and you run:

```
((inc++))
```

...the value of the expression is `0` (because you're using the postfix `++` operator), so the return value is `1`, which means that your script exits when `-e` is in effect.  The easiest way to solve this particular issue is to use the prefix `++` operator:

```
set -ue

inc=0
((++inc))
((++inc))
echo $inc
echo Here
```

**Update**

As @cdarke mentions, you can instead use the `:` command, which is a special shell command that means "do nothing but evaluate all the arguments".  You will often encounter this in shell scripts where it is used to variable defaults like this:

```
: ${SOMEVAR:=somevalue}
```

Or in `while` loops, like this:

```
while :; do
   ...
done
```

So instead of:

```
((inc++))
```

You can do this:

```
: $((inc++))
```

But you'll notice two changes there (and this is why I didn't mention it in my original answer).  Because `:` is itself a command, you can no longer use the `((...))` syntax by itself (which is exactly equivalent to the `let` command).  Instead, you need to use the arithmetic expression syntax, `$((...))`.

You could also do something like this:

```
((inc++)) || true
```

Or even:

```
((inc++)) || :
```

Which similarly have the effect of suppressing the error return code from the expression.

Comment: An alternative (but not necessarily better) syntax is to use the `:` command which always returns success, as in   `: $((inc++))`.

Comment: @cdarke: i'd say that is better; even "much better"

Comment: This is so obvious that I should've figured this out myself.